# GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Button' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've lost all hope, almost.
What im trying to do is basically instantiate a prefab I have which is basically a button with an image, and once instantiated, I want to set a onClick function to be called, but it keeps telling me this error:

GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Button' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface

I dont understand what im doing wrong, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class InventoryCoordinator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject prefabPocion;
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject panelInventuario = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Hotbar");
        if (panelInventuario)
        {
            GameObject primerSlot = panelInventuario.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            GameObject segundoSlot = panelInventuario.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
            GameObject tercerSlot = panelInventuario.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject;
            var newPocion = Instantiate(this.prefabPocion, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            this.SetAndStretchToParentSize((UnityEngine.RectTransform)newPocion.transform.transform, (UnityEngine.RectTransform)primerSlot.transform.transform);
            var button = GameObject.FindWithTag("PotionFreeze").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
            button.clicked += manguito;
            //newPocion.transform.parent = primerSlot.transform;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void manguito()
    {
        Debug.Log("full maracaton");
    }

    public void SetAndStretchToParentSize(UnityEngine.RectTransform _mRect, UnityEngine.RectTransform _parent)
    {
        _mRect.anchoredPosition = _parent.position;
        _mRect.anchorMin = new Vector2(1, 0);
        _mRect.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 1);
        _mRect.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        _mRect.sizeDelta = _parent.rect.size;
        _mRect.transform.SetParent(_parent);
        _mRect.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

I've tried to get the gameObject and cast it, backwards and forwards, and nothing, I need your help guys! Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using the wrong `Button`. Use the `UnityEngine.UI` namespaces instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this issue because you're using `Button` from `UnityEngine.UIElements`, which afaik doesn't support ingame buttons yet (it's for custom editors usage). Use `UnityEngine.UI` instead, and replace:

```
button.clicked += manguito;
```

with

```
button.onClick.AddListener(manguito);
```

Comment: It worked! Do you have an idea why vscode imports me UIElements instead of .UI? It made me loose like 5 hours of my life trying to fix this issue, and even now with the imports you suggest it highlights them in red, despite that on unity engine compiles perfectly =/

Comment: I'm not using VSCode, so can't really help with that. You may check if your setup is correct: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity